# Populate ListView in android from SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, dynamically-generated

I am just learning android programming and now i am making an app that uses database. For now i am using SQLite to store the data.

I have successfully created app which can stored/insert data in a database. Its working and i have checked my database using root Explorer.

Now on 2nd activity lets say DisplayRecords, i want to display my records into list view which will populate dynamically. How can i achieve that through programming.

here is my code of 2nd activity.

```
public class SearchResult extends ActionBarActivity {

ListView ls;
SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_result);

     Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
     setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


     ls = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.displayListView);

 Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM records",null);

     if(c.getCount()==0){
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Records Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     }

     StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

     while(c.moveToNext()){

         buffer.append("Topic"+c.getString(0));
         buffer.append("Description"+c.getString(1));
     }

     //now how can i put the fetched value in ListView

}
```

Can anyone please help me

Thanks

Comment: This is a **skeleton**. Where is the **flesh**?

Comment: @DerGolem i want flesh only becuase i have skeleton

Comment: But it doesn't work like that, here: `StackOverflow is not a Google replacement`. You should search a tutorial and follow it. If you make a mess, then come back with your mess and we'll what can we do to fix it.

Comment: I know its not a google but i want someone to help me in giving code so that i can understand that code and implement in my app.
I have searched on net but its all too complicated to me.
So if u can please help me with my code section because i am still learning.

Comment: You shoud use Google, **first**. Take a tutorial. If you don't understand it, take another one (ther are several ways to do the same thing - choose the one which is best for you). If nothing works, then come with the non working code. But don't ask for code, here.

Comment: @DerGolem brother i have updated my code. Now can u look at and see whats wrong and can you give me solution on how to put that fetched values in ListView

Comment: all tutorials not being equal, I would recommend those from Lars Vogel: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: These are just **random lines** of code taken from some tutorial and **put here and there**, only to seek for some help... Who do you think you are trying to fool?

Answer (score 0):

Class which holds your data

```
 public class Naats_VO {

    private String id;
    private String person_id;
    private String title;
    private String keywords;
    private String language;
    private String type;
    private String length;
    private String url;
    private String fav_count;
    private String hit_count;
    private String release_date;

    public Naats_VO() {
    }

    public Naats_VO(String id, String person_id, String title, String keywords,
            String language, String type, String length, String url,
            String fav_count, String hit_count, String release_date) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.person_id = person_id;
        this.title = title;
        this.keywords = keywords;
        this.language = language;
        this.type = type;
        this.length = length;
        this.url = url;
        this.fav_count = fav_count;
        this.hit_count = hit_count;
        this.release_date = release_date;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPerson_id() {
        return person_id;
    }

    public void setPerson_id(String person_id) {
        this.person_id = person_id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getKeywords() {
        return keywords;
    }

    public void setKeywords(String keywords) {
        this.keywords = keywords;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(String length) {
        this.length = length;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getFav_count() {
        return fav_count;
    }

    public void setFav_count(String fav_count) {
        this.fav_count = fav_count;
    }

    public String getHit_count() {
        return hit_count;
    }

    public void setHit_count(String hit_count) {
        this.hit_count = hit_count;
    }

    public String getRelease_date() {
        return release_date;
    }

    public void setRelease_date(String release_date) {
        this.release_date = release_date;
    }

}
```

Actvity which contains ListView

```
            private List<Naats_VO> naats_list; 
            private Naat_Model db;
            Naats_Adapter adapter ;

            // Initilizae in OnCreate
            naats_list; = new ArrayList<Naats_VO>();
            // Naat_Model is class which communicate with my db.
            db = new Naat_Model(this);

            naats_list = db.getFavorites();

            adapter = new Naats_Adapter(this, naats_list );
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Naat_Model

```
    public class Naat_Model extends _BaseModel {

    // Contacts table name persons
    public static final String TABLE_NAAT = "naats";

    // persons Table Columns names
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_PERSON_ID1 = "person_id";
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_KEYWORDS = "keywords";
    public static final String KEY_LANG1 = "language";
    public static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";
    public static final String KEY_LENGTH = "length";
    public static final String KEY_URL = "url";
    public static final String KEY_FAV_COUNT = "fav_count";
    public static final String KEY_HIT_COUNT = "hit_count";
    public static final String KEY_RELEASE_DATE = "release_date";
    public static final String KEY_FAVR = "favorite";
    public static final String KEY_RECENT = "recent";
    public static final String KEY_DOWNLOAD_STATUS = "status";
    public static final String KEY_DOWNLOAD_id = "downloader_id";
    public static final String KEY_NOTIFICATION_ID = "notifiaction_id";
    public static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private Context _context;

    public Naat_Model(Context context) {
        super(TABLE_NAAT, context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        _context = context;
    }

    public List<Naats_VO> getFavorites() {

        List<Naats_VO> Naats_list = new ArrayList<Naats_VO>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAAT + " WHERE "
                + KEY_FAVR + " = 1";

        Database dbHelper = new Database(_context);
        this.db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Naats_VO naats = new Naats_VO();

                naats.setId(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
                naats.setPerson_id(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PERSON_ID1)));
                naats.setTitle(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TITLE)));
                naats.setKeywords(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_KEYWORDS)));
                naats.setLanguage(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LANG1)));
                naats.setType(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TYPE)));
                naats.setLength(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LENGTH)));
                naats.setUrl(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_URL)));
                naats.setFav_count(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FAV_COUNT)));
                naats.setHit_count(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_HIT_COUNT)));
                naats.setRelease_date(c.getString(c
                        .getColumnIndex(KEY_RELEASE_DATE)));

                // Adding contact to list
                Naats_list.add(naats);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        c.close();
        // return contact list
        return Naats_list;
    }
```

This class will connect your db with app
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fFtD.png

```
    public class Database extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "naat_collection";

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public Database(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // super(context, DATABASE_NAME,
        // context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath(), null,
        // DATABASE_VERSION);

       }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, work with database in Android it's big area, I will try to give you some direction.

First of all you should use [ContentResolver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html) instead of direct call to the database to obtain the Cursor, it helps avoid UI hanging on a tough query because ContentResolver execute query in separate thread.

To solve your task (populate ListView with data and update it on change) Android provides Loaders mechanism.

You have to use [LoaderManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html) by [getLoaderManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getLoaderManager()) method in the Activity. Then implement LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks (I will refer it as loaderCollback)

In the *loaderCallback* method *onCreateLoader* you should create particular [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) (it will do all stuff to correctly query db in separate thread)

After init the loader in the *loaderCallback* method *onLoadFinished* you will receive your cursor, all you need to do it's call [swapCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#swapCursor(android.database.Cursor)) method for the ListView's CursorAdapter. And finally the magic: you have to write something like this

```
cursor.setNotificationUri(getActivity.getContentResolver(), queryUri)
```

That's all from high view.

For more details you can check this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Seriously speaking i didn't understand any think u said. From what u said i have came to conclusion is that its hard to for me and i still need to learn a lot about data handling.

Any ways, thanks for your time and answer. +1

Comment: Just investigate links from the answer :) also you should vote for the answer if it's helpful not in comment but with toggle on the left ;-)

Comment: i will check it. I can't vote because my reputation is not above 15 and i am unable to vote.